# How extract content from Fubarcoder Restsharp client?

Tags: c#, uwp, restsharp

Original Restsharp doesn't support UWP and I use the FubarCoder.Restsharp.Portable package.
I use

```
var request = new RestRequest(host, Method.GET);
var response = await client.Execute<HttpWebResponse>(request);
```

and `response.RawBytes` is raw bytes array. How do I extract data from this? My response contains epub file and I need save this to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need the path of your file to which you want to write, *note that you can't simply write to any path in UWP*. You can find a list of all accessible locations on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Then simply use File.WriteAllBytes method to dump the byte array into the file.

```
IRestResponse response = await client.Execute(request);
byte[] bytes = response.RawBytes;
File.WriteAllBytes(yourFile.Path, bytes);
```